# Thread completion times with thread.join()

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently working with Threads in a production application. I want to know - If threads all have the same defined, static workload, will they complete and suspend in order? For example, if I create thread1, thread2, thread3 in a loop & have them add values up to 1,000, will they *always* finish in the order that they were created?

I did some testing of this theory utilizing the join() method, and the theory (on the surface) appears to be true.

```
public class ThreadingMain implements Runnable{

    public static int total;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadingMain(), i+"");
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        add();

    }


    private static void add() {

        int i = 100000;

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            total += j;
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished");

    }

}
```

I get the following output:

```
0 finished
1 finished
2 finished
...
12 finished
13 finished
14 finished
```

Remove the join() and this is no longer the case, as expected.

In essence, will Threads with the *same workload* always complete in
order? Are there any variables to this?

Comment: You get an order because you wait for the completion of each thread before you even start the next one. The actual workload is entirely irrelevant here, you just made the entire program sequential.

Comment: That edit (`t = null;` and *extra* `t.join();`) just messed up the code, it didn't make the threads run at the same time. You need to store all the `Thread` objects in an array or `List`, and `start()` them in one loop, then `join()` them in a **different loop**, so they all get started before you begin joining.

Comment: Yep, thanks Holger & Andreas. I understand now that the join(); earlier made the program sequential. It had nothing to do with the workload. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: The extra `t.join()` throws an `IllegalThreadStateException`. You haven't executed this code.

Comment: Removed the edits from the original post. The edits I made didn't really make sense and changed the nature of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a CPU has a limited amount of cores and possible executing threads at a time, the operating system needs to manage when and how long a thread gets CPU time for execution. This is done by the scheduler of the operating system.

Here you can read a bit about that: [CPU Scheduling in Operating Systems](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpu-scheduling-in-operating-systems/)

How the threads are managed by your operating system is something that you cannot influence effectively from within your code. You don't have a guarantee that, say, thread `A` will finish before thread `B` even if `A` was created before `B`.

As well, keep in mind that the threads you create are not the only ones the operating system is managing at a time. There are many more processes/programs that are not part of your code, but are involved in the scheduling.